# Is $\langle \overline{x}-\alpha, \overline{y}-\beta\rangle$ a principal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x^3-y^2\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand better  the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x^3-y^2\rangle$ and if I did well they are of this form $\langle \overline{x}-\alpha, \overline{y}-\beta\rangle$ and I'd like to know if they are principal, but I'm really stuck with this.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show for example that $\langle \bar x - 1, \bar y - 1 \rangle$ is not principal.

To see this, note that $$\mathbb{C}[x,y] / \langle x^3 - y^2 \rangle \simeq \mathbb{C}[t^2, t^3]$$ via an isomorphism where $\bar x \mapsto t^2, \bar y \mapsto t^3$.  Here, we can also view $\mathbb{C}[t^2, t^3]$ as the set of $p \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ such that the coefficient of $t^1$ is 0.  Now, suppose to the contrary that $\langle \bar x - 1, \bar y - 1 \rangle$ were a principal ideal; then $\langle t^2 - 1, t^3 - 1 \rangle$ would have to be a principal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[t^2, t^3]$.  Suppose the generator is $p(t)$.  Then since $t^2 - 1$ is a multiple of $p$, we would have to have $p$ of the form $\lambda, \lambda(t-1), \lambda(t+1)$, or $\lambda(t^2-1)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$.  Out of these forms, $\lambda(t-1)$ and $\lambda(t+1)$ are not in $\mathbb{C}[t^2, t^3]$; and $\lambda$ would generate the unit ideal giving a contradiction since $\langle t^2 - 1, t^3 - 1 \rangle$ is not the unit ideal.

We are left with the only possibility being that $p(t) = \lambda(t^2-1)$.  However, then $t^3-1$ is not a multiple of $p$ (even in the larger ring $\mathbb{C}[t]$), giving a contradiction in this case as well.

Comment: Thanks. It is so helpful